# New to python (4days) mystery error

Tags: python

```
from __future__ import division
import decimal
print "Type the total population"
a = float (raw_input())#population
print "type the number of seats"
b = raw_input()#seats
d = int(a) / int(b)
print "The Devisor is:",
print d
print "Type state population"
s = float (raw_input())
one = int(s) / int(d)
print "States  standard quota is:",
print one
print "Type next states population"
s = float (raw_input())
two = int(s) / int(d)
print "States  standard quota is:",
print two


print "Type next states population"
s = float (raw_input())
three = int(s) / int(d)
print "States  standard quota is:",
print three

print "Type next states population"
s = float (raw_input())
four = int(s) / int(d)
print "States  standard quota is:",
print four

print "Type next states population"
s = float (raw_input())
five = int(s) / int(d)
print "States  standard quota is:",
print five

print "list of states standard quotas"
print one
print two
print three
print four
print five
x = int(one) + int(two) + int(three) + int(four) + int(five)
print "type decimals one at a time"
e = float (raw_input())
f = raw_input()
g = raw_input()
h = raw_input()
i = raw_input()
z = int(e) + int(f) + int(g) + int(h) + int(i) # This is where error is
print "distribute following from highest to lowest decimal"
print int(z)
```

raw_input("press any key to continue:")

enter code here

----- This is my code for a calculator I'm making for Hamilton method of distribution of representation in Congress, it will save me time in math and it gave me something to practice with that I actually care about. Everything works fine until the point I've commented #error on. Normally I would test in IDLE python shell but it won't work because of input needed in the raw_inports. Remember, I'm very new to python so I know my code is most likely inefficient. Also I've been having an issue with getting a result of 0 if the error does not occur which should have been all decimals added up, equaling a small number between 1 and 3 (usually )

Comment: I don't think you have put `#error` anywhere in your code...

Comment: Sorry forgot it, deep, Just edited

Comment: I can see the `#error` comment. But what would be more useful is if you gave us the actual error message...

Comment: Give a related output, including the error message and traceback

Comment: I wish I could, it flashes for a sec then crashes. AMD it seems raw inport does not work in python IDE environment thing fir testing code, sorry if I'm wrong, very new

Comment: I also had no idea you guys would be so fast responding, I need to go for now so sorry. I'm checking back later. In the future illnpost only when I have time to watch.

Comment: First, an error will only occur if you can't cast to `int`. Second you can add a `raw_input` at the end so that it does not `flash` if you don't have an error. Third WTAF, you `don't have time` and `in the future`???

Comment: Judging from `type decimals one at a time` and `e = float (raw_input())`, I think you have to calculate `z` as `z = float(e) + float(f) + float(g) + float(h) + float(i)`

Comment: @Taharix Next time you post a question and add a tag to it, if you put your mouse cursor over the tag you'll see the number of people who follow that tag (people who have their question feed dynamic and adaptable to what tag they choose). If you look, Python has 48.9k followers, so there's an extremely high chance you'll get a reply from someone in a short time and also an answer if you formulated your question correctly.

Comment: @dmg On my way to school, but I do have raw inport at end, it crashes due to error. And I'm very new, ante you saying I'm using the int tag wrong somewhere? Also what id WTAF. Thank you for putting up with me, this is my first time on a site like this, and I'm a newcomer to Python.

Comment: In the future calls a function from python 3 that lets you have ling decimals, and @rawing I will try that, thank you.

Comment: @radu thank you fir the info, it will help in the future, I can tell some people are mad with this post, so ill make sure to clean them up in the future.

Comment: @rawing Your suggestion worked! Thank you. How do I mark your post as answered ?

Comment: @Taharix: Hold on, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with floating point numbers, you have to use `float` instead of `int` to convert the user input to a number:

```
z = float(e) + float(f) + float(g) + float(h) + float(i)
```